# Mac OS X Mountain Lion adding www to virtual host on localhost

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, virtualhost

I'm new to configuring my Mac for localhost so this may be a dumb question.  I want to set up a virtual host so that `http://localhost/domain` points to `http://domain.dev`.  In my Apache configuration, I have localhost pointing to my Sites folder.  That works correctly.  I can browse to localhost/domain.

In my hosts file, I set up domain.dev as `127.0.0.1`.

In my vhosts file, I set up the following entry:

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites/domain/"
ServerName domain.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I uncomment this line in the Apache configuration:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

The browser adds "www" to the domain.dev, which it then can't find.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias).

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
   DocumentRoot /Users/username/Sites/domain/
   ServerName domain.dev
   ServerAlias www.domain.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that the server www.domain.dev cannot be found.  I restarted Apache.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a way to prevent it from adding the "www"?

Comment: Try just putting in the IP address for localhost (127.0.0.1), or just putting in `localhost`. Unless you're running a DNS server and have added the `domain.dev` domain as an `A` record in a zone file, it won't resolve.